# Does one need a differential equation to do boundary layer theory?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, perturbation-theory, substitution

I'm trying to understand permutation theory and in particular the $$z=\frac{x}{\epsilon}$$ substitution to get an inner solution.

Here is my toy example: $$f(x)=\sqrt{x} - x^{1/\epsilon}$$ and I'm interested in the interval $[0,1]$.

[image]

Does it count as two time scales and a boundary layer at $x=1$?

So we balance the original and, as I presume because in $[0,1)$ we have $$x^{1 / \epsilon} \in o \left(\sqrt x \right), \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0,$$ we drop it and get $$f_\text{outer} = \sqrt x.$$

Now we substitute $$z=\frac{x-1}{\epsilon}$$ ($x-1$ because the layer is at $1$)  and get $$f(z)=\sqrt{\epsilon z +1} - (\epsilon z +1)^{1 / \epsilon}.$$

The two terms don't seem to be of different order as $\epsilon \to 0$. How can we get $f_\text{inner}$?

Comment: Really, you need a differential equation to do boundary layer theory. I don't know what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @David: I have borrowed your first sentence and changed the title, if you don't mind.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @David: I'm trying to understand the essence of boundary layer theory in particular (and permutation theory in general). And I suspect that even though it's most frequently used for analyzing DEs, the presence of DEs in most examples I've seen rather obscures things for someone who hasn't seen permutation theory before and wants to understand the tool itself, before applying it.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Perturbation theory is a tool to help understand solutions to equations. Without equations, there is nothing to study. Instead of differential equations, try solving quadratic equations with small parameters. There is an example in the [perturbation theory tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/perturbation-theory/info), and you should be able to find more on this website, or other sites or books.